# Time complexity of counting cycles and complete subgraphs of a given size

Tags: time-complexity, graph-theory, computational-geometry

I am very new to graph theory and I am trying to understand the following. Given an undirected graph G with V vertexes and E edges, what is the time complexity of counting all the complete subgraphs of size k and what is the time complexity of counting all the cycles of length k? Basically, which one is faster? I am only considering cases where k is even. Are there any well-known references for this?

Answer (score 0):

Counting all cycles of length k can, in general, be achieved in O(VE) time (V = number of vertices, E = number of edges), although this number can be greatly improved depending on k ([Ref](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/ayz4.pdf)). Counting all complete subgraphs or cliques can be achieved in O(n<sup>k</sup> k<sup>2</sup>) in the general case, but again, this number can be improved upon depending on the structure of the graph and algorithm used ([Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)).